# AutoHotKey run/activate SQL server management studio

Tags: autohotkey

Hi everyone I am struggling with AutoHotKey and simple key binding.

What I am trying to achieve is that if ssms is not running, start it, otherwise set focus/active this program. At the moment I have something like this:

```
+!s::
StringCaseSense, On
process, exist, Ssms.exe
{
    If !errorLevel
        Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"
    else 
        IfWinExist Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
            WinActivate 
}
```

This is working pretty fine until I create/open any SQL script in ssms. Any ideas how to fix this script?

Comment: What is that code block doing there? `Process` is not a conditional statement! That's why you're checking `ErrorLevel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simplified version of what I use for all of my shortcuts. It uses a function (that can be reused). The first parameter is text in the window title. The second is the exe path.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

+!s::ShowStart("Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe")

ShowStart(title, exe)
{
    IfWinExist, %title%
        WinActivate
    else
    {
        Run, %exe%,, UseErrorLevel
        If ErrorLevel
        {
            Msgbox, Exe not found.
            Return
        }
        WinActivate
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this works just fine and it also reduce amount of code required to achieve same for multiple programs. +1

Comment: I wanted to share a slightly off-topic note since this page came up in my search for a solution.   AutoHotkey's `IfWinActive` may fail to detect SSMS if your script is not running as Admin.

Answer (score 0):

That code should work for you:

```
+!s::
StringCaseSense, On
Process, Exist, Ssms.exe
if ErrorLevel
{
    IfWinExist, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
    {
        WinActivate
    }
}
else
{
    Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
}
return
```

Here is also same code but for notepad.exe , which I have tested and it works fine:

```
+!s::
StringCaseSense, On
Process, Exist, notepad.exe
if ErrorLevel
{
    IfWinExist, Untitled - Notepad
    {
        WinActivate
    }
}
else
{
    Run, c:\Windows\notepad.exe
}
return
```